# VBA recordset Looping from cell value

Tags: mysql, vba, ado

I have a query table and transfer to excel. I loop from cell range to re-query into database and it works fine but it really take so much time since i used below code.. The code need to query and do recordset every time satified IF condition in each single cell. Is there other way that this code will execute in database server and once complete then, only do a recordset?

```
     'Set Connection
      Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=" & _
      Server_Name & ";Port=" & Port & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
      ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

   'Set Recordset
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    rs.CursorLocation = 3
    rs.Open SQLQuery, Cn, adOpenStatic


    myArray = rs.GetRows()


    kolumner = UBound(myArray, 1) 'Count number of Columns
    rader = UBound(myArray, 2) 'count number of rows

    For K = 0 To kolumner ' Using For loop data are displayed
    Range("A5").Offset(0, K).Value = rs.Fields(K).Name 'Field is the header 
    of each column and not included in Array. Field(0) means header of first 
    column.

    For R = 0 To rader
        Range("A5").Offset(R + 1, K).Value = myArray(K, R)

    Next
    Next




    set rows = 0 to rader

    Range("L5").Value = "Debug Note" 'insert Name of Column

    For R = 6 To 1100

    Datevalue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & R)

    Dateexcel = FORMAT(Datevalue, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    SQLQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM Mfg.databasemodels_note " & _
                "where typeId = " & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & R) & " AND 
                 date > " & "'" & Dateexcel & "'" & " order by date asc 
                 limit 1;"
    Set rs2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs2.CursorLocation = 3 'client
    rs2.Open SQLQuery2, Cn, adOpenStatic
    myArray2 = rs2.GetRows()


    If Not (rs2.BOF And rs2.EOF) And (Range("J" & R).Value = "failed" Or 
    Range("J" & R).Value = "invalid") Then
    Range("L" & R).Value = myArray2(3, 0)
    Else
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    rs2.Close
    Set rs2 = Nothing

    Next
```

Comment: if it works it belongs to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: what database are you using? you should use an explicit definition for ADO objects, that will help for a faster execution. Also, I cannot see where you define your connection, so make sure that you connect once before the code and close it after it. Some people put the connection is a loop or sth which takes forever. Also, reading from range is slower than reading from an array so dump all of your range data into an array and do the reading from the array not from the range/cells

Comment: adding connection code..